# Creating Environment Variables in Linux using PHP

Tags: php, linux

I want to create user defined Environment Variables in LINUX using PHP.
I tried it using putenv() but it persist only to current request.

Also I tried to execute it using backticks.
as 
 `VARNAME="777";`;
`export VARNAME`;

But it does not show up the variable and value on printing printenv.
How can I create environment Variable using php.

How do I execute
               VARNAME="777"; export VARNAME
using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `exec("export VARNAME=777");`

But...

I don't believe there is such a thing as a persistent environment between requests with apache. One thing that you might want to do to get environment setup for a particular command is to set up a text file somewhere accessible by apache and populate it with your environment variables, one per line

```
VARNAME=777
MY_VAR=COOL
```

Then create a function like this run with environment

```
function runWithEnvironment($cmd, $envronmentFile, &$output){
    $env = file ($environmentFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach($env as $line){
        putenv($line);
    }
    $ret=null;
    exec($cmd, $output, $ret);
    return $ret;
}
```

This should abstract out setting up the environment prior to execution of your command.

Comment: I tried but its not working. Its showing up  its previous value. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know that apache runs in a real shell so I don't think persistent environment variables are on the table.

Comment: what are you looking to do ... there may be a serviceable work around to accomplish your goal without relying on a persistent environment.

Comment: I want to create and export an environment variable using PHP that will be accessed by another Perl program. I should be able to lookup the variable using printenv. (i.e. the env variable should persist in the system till user unset it)

Comment: As long as php is the one calling the perl script in the same request then that should work.

Comment: I am not able to look up variable value using  echo $MY_VAR. I guess variable is not getting created.

Comment: based on [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) by default with safe mode on you can only use putenv on environment variables that start with `PHP_`.